# How do I select all objects in an SVG imported into Inkscape from Google Draw?

Tags: inkscape

How do I select all objects in an SVG imported into Inkscape from Google Draw?

When I try and select all objects individually so I can export each object as a separate image  (export to bitmap) it will only select the entire imported SVG.

I want to be able to import individual images as layers into Photoshop since we can't directly edit SVGs.

File:

https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7908924_855_863732581
http://bayfiles.com/file/NVHz/rhWuQr/Exported_from_Google_Draw.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the objects are grouped. Ungroup them by selecting the group and go to `Object > Ungroup` (alternatively rightclick and select `Ungroup` or use `Shift+Ctrl+G`).